# Weird Issue with IE 10 for SVG and angular

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, svg

I am facing a weird issue from past week. One of my application where-in I have used SVG for rendering. The things are working good on Chrome,Safari and Mozilla.

Output is below image for the browser:![Chrome,Safari and Mozilla output][1]

Now here I used SVG and provided the the same id to textpath for attribute "d" as mention in open forums(How to create arc using svg).

Now when I run same code on IE. Output are really very weird. My text is not taking the path of arc. 
I am using angular for this project.
Output for IE:
![IE Output][2]

Please help me why this issue is happening. I tried lots of blog but none work. Majorly with geometric precision. 
Rest are:
[SVG is not rendering in IE 10 with Doctype HTML 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772026/svg-is-not-rendering-in-ie-10-with-doctype-html-4)
[SVG is not rendering in IE 10 with Doctype HTML 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772026/svg-is-not-rendering-in-ie-10-with-doctype-html-4)

Comment: Please fix your broken links.  We can't tell what might be wrong from your description.

Comment: The chrome result is http://creativity-labs.com/RefrenceImage/ChromeSnap.png

The IE result are http://creativity-labs.com/RefrenceImage/IEissue.png

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the SVG output your code produces, so we can see for ourselves what is going wrong in IE?

Comment: Ys sure actually you can take live example
smtest14.com
then click the chocolate on home page 
Enter username: test@test.com
password:test

Then you come to page where bug is NOW ADD TEXT(ABC) 
Type any text in the text box then click ADD
Now in extreme right side curve (circle ,arc ) are there 
Click those and see the bug which I have provided into snapshot

Comment: Is this is issue with IE rendering, because not getting same on chrome and Mozilla. Even I tried hard coded the values and text but still the text is not taking the path of arc. or this issue is due to angular js can't figure it out

Comment: I am still in issue pls help

Comment: Please post a simplified test case that shows the problem.

Comment: The issue is text is not taking shape of arc in IE when i try to resize same the text trim which is happening in IE. The math behind is same for ie and other browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

Actually in IE I used the  getComputedTextLength() for the text. Before that I mention the font size and text. But forget to mention fontfamily.

Now my width was returning same for all the font because it was considering Arial even I change. Other bowser take this length as per font. But IE we need to provide type of font also. This way it is solved